# How to describe changing status of object

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the correct way to say that I have changed the status of an object? I want to say that I have *statused* or *status'd* the object but the first gets underlined by my spell-checker and the second doesn't look correct.

Comment: You could say you've *flagged* it. Or *[re]categorised, [re]classified],* etc. Although [verbification](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/grammar-verbification.aspx) is a standard feature of (particularly informal) English, I don't think many people (or indeed spell checkers) would accept you doing that with the noun **status**.

Comment: 'status' is a bit ...static, and verbing a static concept sounds more like setting the status rather than changing it from one status to another. Aside from that 'statused' just sounds wrong.

Comment: This question needs to be a bit more specific; what object is having its status changed, and it what way?  If it needs to be as ultra-generic as "change the status of an object", why does it need to be that generic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Status" doesn't really mean anything out of context. The best anyone can do is give you an answer as generic as your question.

In that case,

> I **updated** the object.
>
> I **changed** the object.
>
> I **modified** the object.
>
> I **edited** the object.

Comment: If the status change was specifically to indicate that the object had changed: I **dirtied** the object.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz +1 for good technical terminology (IMHO). When you change the contents/state of something in a program, it is usually termed to be "dirty" until that change is either committed or rolled back. Sadly, the connotation that comes to mind when I see "I dirtied the object" or "I soiled the object" is not always something technical, and usually involves soap and water to correct the situation.

Answer (score 3):

In computer circles, the status of a programming state or condition is a snapshot record and is subject to change.

"The status of variable x is set to some value."
I have a need to status something as being done - meaning I want to record its current state.
The software routine failed to status the returned value of x.
He statused his work as done.

All of the above are of current usage in computer programming circles as well as those using computer programs to show snapshots of workflow states.

Maybe the dictionary folks just haven't caught up with a couple of decades of computer jargon.

My job or workflow status is:
I statused my work as complete.
I am statusing the job complete.

All of these usages need to be added.  They aren't slang.  You can find them spoken and written and any computer programmer would have perfect understanding of what was being said/written.

Comment: I disagree; they absolutely are slang or jargon, and are not at all standard.  (I've never encountered them as a programmer, nor do I recall reading that usage anywhere on the SE network.)

Answer (score 2):

I am in the computer industry and we use "statused" all the time to indicated that a problem report or a job has had its status changed by an individual or a group.  It is a valid use, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a single word that will work here. It is exceptionally accurate to just say:

> **... I changed the status of ...**

if you really want to emphasize something about a 'status'.

Otherwise, simply:

> **... I modified ...**

works.

As a side note, 'statused' or 'status'd' just won't work for many reasons; it's too new, it is semantically a strange verbification 'I concepted the idea', 'I resulted the outcome of the experiment' are similarly difficult. That is, it your suggestions are unlikely to catch on.

Comment: In general, don't try to invent a new word when there is already a perfectly good word to express the same idea. We already have more words in English to express the idea of changing something than we need -- "changed", "modified", "updated", etc -- there's no requirement to invent yet another, "statused".

Answer (score 1):

The most accurate word I can think of is **alter**.

> alter (v): to make different without changing into something else

From [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alter). Since you are changing the status/state of an object, you are making it different. However, since it is still (presumably) the same object, you have not changed it into something else. Perfect fit!

Answer (score 0):

Since the noun **[status](http://www.onelook.com/?w=status&ls=a)** is

> a state at particular time

then making the verb out of it contradicts its own meaning.

Also, status, as a state, is a collection of all or some properties of the object. Changing the status in this sense is very general and can be any kind of change (so it does not justify its own verb and hence there is no exact verb for it; for general changes to the object see [tenfour's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47798/how-to-describe-changing-status-of-object/47802#47802)).

In case you really want to introduce a verb, you might follow the noun **[state](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/state_27)**, which as a verb normally means

> - to express something in speech or writing, especially in a definite or formal way
> - to give information

but the **noun** state can be

> - the condition of something at a particular time

([also](http://www.onelook.com/?w=state&ls=a))

> - the way something is with respect to its main attributes

If you accept that the verb *state* developed from the noun, in a sense 'to give information about something (with respect to its main attributes)'; then, *possibly*,

- *re-state*

might work for you. The main difference is that you do not feel the direct contradiction to its own meaning. However, the sense '*to change the status/state*' is definitively ***not*** immediately obvious and requires context and reflection or the word *has* to be introduced and defined before use (however there is also a potential problem with overshadowing of the other meaning of the verb state).

Comment: I guess the verb/phrase the OP might want is *state-changed* as in *I state-changed the [noun].*

Answer (score 0):

I work in the car rental industry.

I came to this site because I have been looking for the best way to refer to vehicles that has had a change in status.

It may be correct to state that..."Do you have car #123 because the status in the computer shows that it is available at your location?".

But is common spoken and written practice to say instead..."Do you have #123 because it is statused 'available' to your location?" (especially when we keep vigorous notes on all aspects of the rentals (i.e. contracts, customers and units).)

As you see the word status is used differently today.
Nothing physically was altered, changed, edited or modified.